# why does the scipy.optimize flatten the ndarray to 1-d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Please look at the following code.

```
import numpy
def f(u):
    print(u) # to check dimensions of the input 
    return 10
u= numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
scipy.optimize.minimize(f,u)
```

output:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
[ 1.00000001  2.          3.          4.        ]
[ 1.          2.00000001  3.          4.        ]
[ 1.          2.          3.00000001  4.        ]
[ 1.          2.          3.          4.00000001]
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
Out[24]:
      fun: 10
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 6
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

As we can see, the input `u` is a 2d array `u= numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`. However, it has been converted to [ 1.  2.  3.  4.] , which is a 1d array. I don't understand  why does the `scipy.optimize.minimize` do this. Of course, I can always reshape the array within my function. But I would like to know , if I am missing something in the syntax or usage of `scipy.optimize`.

Comment: Hey did your find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No. I workaround by reshaping the array within the objective function.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that every constraint also gets flattened structure, and reshaping is a big pain